# Is there a way to "extract" WPF controls of Expression Blend?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wpf-controls, expression-blend

I am not sure if the WPF controls that make up Expression Blend's UI is packaged in the application in a usable way, like separate assemblies, etc. But if they aren't, is there a way to "extract" these controls so you can have the same controls in your app with the same look and functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look in your install folder for blend under Program Files or Program Files (x86) and there will be style directories with the appropriate resources, I believe.

Otherwise you can use Snoop to look at WPF application structure and get what you need
http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/

Or a tool like DumpControlTemplate to pull it out of Blend, I know a few people that have done this.

http://www.simple-talk.com/content/print.aspx?article=1032

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that when you find a way that it is legal.

Comment: I am not gonna use it for a public app, just a personal app.

Comment: OK, the last time I looked some controls resided in a common expression studio folder in some DLLs. You can easily use Reflector to find out where.

Comment: Thanks emo, you mean using reflector on expression blend? I thought it would be obfuscated, is it not?

Comment: It might be but that won't keep you from using them

Comment: Can copying a style of RadioBox from ExpressionBlend for example be illegal? just wondering of application of legal question on elements style ..

Comment: @ValentinKuzub: Yes, that can be illegal. You will have to look at the copyrights the control(s) came with.

Comment: Damn I am so bad with licenses, is it ok if I ask you to maybe point me on a license I could use as sample for my SL application, so others cannot steal my XAML controls legally? I got some interesting controls/styles and wouldn't want them to be stolen tbh.

Comment: @ValentinKuzub, The best thing you can do is search SO, if there is no similar question, ask this as a separate question so you'll get the answers from the SO community.